# RoR ruby -- undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

I'm having a trouble with the update on a class.

This is the view:

```
    <div id = "list">
        <%= form_for @list do |form| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: form.object %>
        <div class="list_fields">
         <%= form.text_field :name, placeholder:
```

and this is the controller:

```
     def update
         if @list.update_attributes(params[:list])
            flash[:success] = "List updated"
         else
            render 'edit'
         end
         redirect_to @list
    end
```

The routes are:

```
       resources :lists, only: [:create, :show, :destroy,:edit]
```

Now the problem is it keeps raising

```
      "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" 
           in line 2  --->   <%= form_for @list do |form| %>
```

And I can't seem to figure out why. 
Thanks in advance 
Leo

Comment: you do realise the `<%= form.text_field :name, placeholder:` line is incomplete, right?

Comment: yes it's just a portion of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the `@list` before you update its attributes.

```
def update
  @list = List.find_by_id(params[:id])
  if @list.update_attributes(params[:list])
    flash[:success] = "List updated"
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
  redirect_to @list
end
```

And by the way, the problem you see is not caused by your update action but by your edit action that redirects to this view.

You have to load the @list in both actions. In edit action in order to render the view, in update action in order to update the appropriate object.

Comment: You could simplify the first line: @list = List.find(params[:id])